# How do I go about this?

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

An  entomologist  is  interested  in  evaluating  a  new  chemical  formulation  for  possible  use as  a  pesticide  for  controlling  fire  ants.  She  decides  to  compare  its  performance relative  to  the  most  widely  used  pesticide  on  the  market,  AntKiller.  Each  of  the pesticides  is  applied  to  100  containers  of  fire  ants.  The  new  pesticide  successfully killed  all  the  fire  ants  within  two  hours  of  application  in  65  of  the  100  containers. Of  the 100  containers treated  with AntKiller only  59  had  all fire ants killed.
a)  Is  there  significant  evidence  that  the  proportion  of  containers  successfully treated  by  the  new  formulation  is  greater  than  the  proportion  of  containers successfully  treated  by  AntKiller?  Test  at alpha=0.05 and use  the P-value approach.

Comment: We have you tried ?

Comment: I tried using the z test formula but there's no standard deviation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A$ represent the new pesticide and $B$ be the AntKiller. Then, you are given that $\bar{x}_A = \frac{65}{100} = 0.65$ and $\bar{x}_B = \frac{59}{100} = 0.59$. You know need to find sample variance for both, $$s_A^2 = \sum_n (x_i - \bar{x}_A)^2 = 65(1-0.65)^2 + 35(0-0.65)^2 = 22.75$$ $$s_B^2 = \sum_n(x_i-\bar{x}_B)^2 = 59(1-0.59)^2 + 41(0-0.59)^2 = 24.19$$
You can know do a test for significance $$t = \frac{(\bar{x}_A - \bar{x}_B)}{\sqrt{\frac{s_A}{n_A}+\frac{s_B}{n_B}}}$$
and derive the conclusion from there.

Comment: How do I find degrees of freedom for that t-test? Do I use this formula? (( SA^2÷nA)+(SB^2÷nA))/((SA^2÷nA)÷(nA-1))+((SB^2÷nB)÷(nB-1))